# Visual Studio Referencing Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, msbuild

I'm currently experiencing some referencing issue with my projects. I have a web project which is directly referencing my framework project (which handles database connectivity mainly) and my framework project references an external assembly (lets name it Oracle.Connectivity.dll) and the Oracle.Connectivity.dll has a dependency on Microsoft.Data.Edm version 5.6. The dependency hierarchy looks as such:

web project -> framework project -> Orable.Connectivity.dll -> Microsoft.Data.Edm v5.6

For some reason my framework project is having some runtime issue with Microsoft.Data.Edm version 5.6 so I had to explicitly set it to use version 5.6.1 of Microsoft.Data.Edm. Everything worked fine when I build the framework project - the correct version of Microsoft.Data.Edm would get copied to the output folder for the particular project itself.

However I build my web project what I was seeing is that MSBuild will take the version 5.6 instead of 5.6.1. Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Comment: How are you doing this explicit binding - through the app/web.config or through VS binary references ?

Comment: through binary references.